# how to create a windows environment in linux

Tags: linux, windows

I am trying to run windows software in fedora OS. There option of dual booting. But is there a way of creating a virtual environment, like we create environment for various python project, in which we can run .exe files and use microsoft office softwares (word, excel, etc.)? It's a weird question, but I searched the internet but not able to find it out.

Comment: Try using wine for install .exe on linux

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can easily do so with the help of VmWare or VrtualBox, or any other similar applications.With a virtual machine application like VMware, you can run another operating system inside your current operating system.
It's running an OS inside another OS,also, you can store and run multiple OS (not simultaneously though) with the hep of these virtual machines.